# Is there a way to give the ChoiceSet a dynamic array of choices in an adaptive card?

Tags: adaptive-cards, bot-framework-composer

I am getting some data from an API call and I want to display them in an adaptive card as a choice set, then the user will be able to choose one or more choices to do action on them. The problem is that the array of choices is dynamic. My question is how to pass an array to the choice set in the adaptive card. I am writing the adaptive card on https://adaptivecards.io/designer/

here is an example of what I want:
[image]

Comment: Would you please share the adaptive card JSON (with static/example values) that you are wanting it to look like? I can then give you the steps on how to populate that with dynamic values from Composer/adaptive expressions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got how to do it. I can simply add the array I have in the composer to the choices in the adaptive card.

Comment: @DanaV sorry, I need your help once again! In the same example, if an object in the array is like this: {“title”:”a **bold** text”,”value”:”A”} the bold word is not bolded on Microsoft teams, it is displayed as it is with **. It is bolded normally on webchat but doesn’t on teams. Can you help  solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way to do this:

Set the array in this way, each value has title and value as choices:
[image]

And from the adaptive card, in the ChoiceSet, call it this way:
[image]